# Arvei Nachal Translation

Tags: commentaries, chasidut-hasidism

Does anyone know if there is a published English or Spanish translation of the sefer **Arvei Nachal** by Rabbi David Shlomo Eibshitz?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.shlomokluger.com/translated-books/arvei-nachal/arvei-nachal